# Omniauth + Facebook Mutual Friends Count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, devise, omniauth

Is there a better/easier way to find mutual friends between users than creating a Friends table and logging the UIDs of each new user's friends? (Using Devise + Omniauth on Rails 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to log all UIDs. Are you using facebook provider ? If so, you can use Koala or FBGraph gems to form an FQL to find of there are any common friends.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the `oauth_access_token` available, you can use the [koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) gem.

```rb
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_access_token)
friends = @graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
```